# Is there a way to log all file modifications in Mac OS X?

Tags: macos, filesystems

Is there a way to log all the files that are being modified?

The situation is that I want to investigate a suspicious program. So I start the logging, run the program and afterwards quit the logging and go through the list of files.

I’m using this dtrace snippet but it also includes reads:

```
dtrace -n 'syscall::open*:entry { printf("%s %s",execname,copyinstr(arg0)); }'
```

It would be quite useful to have a list of just the files that were modified.

Comment: You can restrict it to only `open`s with write-access by testing `arg1` as well. Alternatively, you could see if filtering the output of `fs_usage` gets you the information you're looking for, or write a small tool using the `FSEventStream` API.